# Random sample generator

Tags: python, random

Any suggestion for random sample generation? I need to pick random 100 items from a large list every time I run it. I can do it by just comparing IDs of items and looping until count reaches a 100, but I am wondering if there are any built in features that can simplify this process.

Comment: I posted a solution for a similar problem (sample size unknown in advance), but it actually is a random sample generator and can be a solution to your question too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30063866/694360

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [`random.sample(population, k)`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample).

> Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence. Used for random sampling without replacement.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`random.sample`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
import random
x = range(10000)
y = random.sample(x, 100)
```